# Connection between AngularJS and Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new using angular in MVC, I'm tring to read data from my controller make with ASP.NET MVC EF, to angular.
I'm try with this:

I added in my MVC Controller (the path is '/Controllers/BrandController.cs') this code:

```
public JsonResult GetBrands()
        {
            var result = db.Brands.ToList();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And then in the file js I put both service and controller of angular, that is the code:

```
var BrandApp = angular.module('BrandApp', []);

//Controller
BrandApp.controller('BrandController', function ($scope, BrandService) {

    getBrands();
    function getBrands() {
        BrandService.getBrands()
            .success(function (items) {
                $scope.brands = items;
                console.log($scope.brands);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    }

});

//service
BrandApp.factory('BrandService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var BrandService = {};
    BrandService.getBrands = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetBrands');
    };
    return BrandService;

}]);
```

What I'm wrong?

Thanks for you answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the controller name is `BrandController`, URL should be `/Brand/GetBrands`.

```
BrandService.getBrands = function () {
   return $http.get('/Brand/GetBrands');
};
```

Normally, when you dealing with that kind of problem, you want to debug using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Chrome Plugin PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), or some other tools.

Answer (score 0):

If your C# controller is 'BrandController' then the URL should be /Brand/GetBrands. Simply modify your $http method like so:

```
BrandService.getBrands = function () {
    return $http.get('/Brand/GetBrands');
};
```

It is also good practice to add the `[HttpGet]` attribute above the `GetBrands` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
return $http.get('/Brand/GetBrands');
```

Answer (score 0):

Win is right. Also I see a problem when you define your angular controller.
You have

```
BrandApp.controller('BrandController', function ($scope, BrandService) {
...
})
```

And you should have something like that:

```
BrandApp.controller('BrandController', ['$scope', 'BrandService', function ($scope, BrandService) { ... }])
```

Every time you add a dependency you have to add it to to an array that is the second parameter and to parameter list of anonymous function in the end of that array.

Also you should always use array as second argument even if your controller looks like:

```
MyApp.controller('MyController', [function() { ... }])
```

It just safer. If I remember correctly some version of angular could break (but not always) if it's missing.